# How to call a method defined in another class

Tags: objective-c

I have a class named as Backgroundmusic.h file is

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h"

@interface Backgroundmusic : NSObject{  
}

-(void)playBgmusic:(BOOL) issoundon;

@end
```

Backgroundmusic.m is

```
-(void)playBgmusic:(BOOL)issoundon {
    //AVAudioPlayer *myExampleSound; //this variable can be named differently

if ( issoundon==TRUE) {

        NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"bg" ofType:@"wav"];
        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                     ,&soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
    else {
        NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nil ofType:@"wav"];
        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                     ,&soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}
```

Basically what i am trying to do is setting a background music to my app at the time of beginning and allow the user to stop it in the middle
so in my xAppdelegate.m i have called this function as

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    Backgroundmusic *bgm=[[Backgroundmusic alloc] init];
    [bgm playBgmusic:TRUE];
}
```

but at this time my app terminates can someone tell me whats the issue here???

Comment: Have you actually `#import`-ed `BackgroundMusic.h`?

Comment: What's the error message you get when your app terminates?  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?  `NSException`?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

what the error message you are getting ? When application terminate you can check that in gdb window. It will show the proper error message. Post that error message in this thread.

Comment: ectually i am getting "The program being debugged is not being run." from the long time but mp app is working on the device.But due to this error i am not able to use the debugger .So Sorry i cant tell u the error.